# Specific withdraw function in python

Tags: python

I'm taking a course in Cousera and there is a python function that I can't get it correct, could you please help me out?

```
class BankAccount:
""" Class definition modeling the behavior of a simple bank account """

def __init__(self, initial_balance):
    """Creates an account with the given balance."""
    self._balance = initial_balance;
    self._fee = 0;
def deposit(self, amount):
    """Deposits the amount into the account."""
    self._balance += amount;
def withdraw(self, amount):
    """
    Withdraws the amount from the account.  Each withdrawal resulting in a
    negative balance also deducts a penalty fee of 5 dollars from the balance.
    """
    if(self._balance - amount < 0):
        self._fee += 5;
        self._balance -= 5;
        self._balance -=  amount;

    else:
        self._balance -=  amount;
def get_balance(self):
    """Returns the current balance in the account."""
    return self._balance;
def get_fees(self):
    """Returns the total fees ever deducted from the account."""
    return self._fee;
```

testcode:(The test code and expect result should be 10 and 5)

```
my_account = BankAccount(10)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(20)
print my_account.get_balance(), my_account.get_fees()
```

It seem like my code can pass the test code I provided but I can't get the result that the course want, and I can't provide that since I myself don't know what the expected answer is...(The grader won't show me the correct answer)
The actual problem:

```
my_account = BankAccount(10)
my_account.withdraw(5)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(30)
my_account.withdraw(10)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(50) 
my_account.deposit(30)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.deposit(30)
my_account.withdraw(25) 
my_account.withdraw(5)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(10) 
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.deposit(30)
my_account.withdraw(25) 
my_account.withdraw(10)
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(10)
my_account.withdraw(5) 
print my_account.get_balance(), my_account.get_fees()
```

Comment: include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it

Comment: You'll need to tell us what the problem is!

Comment: "The test code and expect result should be 10 and 5" <- The test code result IS 10 and 5!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion earlier, I have fixed it

Comment: "I can't provide that since I myself don't know what the expected answer is" <- then your question is completely pointless and unanswerable.

Comment: I just think that there might be some problem in the withdraw method, like logical problems that I didn't notice, again sorry if that's pointless, is there any advice on how to solve this? Maybe other forum and stuff? Thanks

Comment: One last question: If you don't know the expected result, how do you know that your result is not the expected result?

Comment: the website has a grader where you submit your answer, but i wouldn't give me the correct answer...

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in the `withdraw()` method. Double check that you are running the correct sequence of withdrawals and deposits, and the correct initial balance. Or ... maybe the grader has a bug.